# SQL. How to exclude a statement from Actual Exec Plan?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

SQL 2008. I am running sproc from SQL Studio and when I try to get Actual Execution Plan it blows up the tempdb.

I narrowed the problem down to call to a row scalar function which is used on 700K rows table.

I deduced that SQL is trying to create 700K exec plans for that function and writes all the data to tempdb which has 3Gb free space..

I dont really need to see the plan for that function.

Can I explicitely exclude a statement from generation of exec plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't exclude it from a execution plan, other than removing the call from the query.

It does however, sound like a prime candidate to switch from a scalar UDF to an inline table UDF. Scalar UDFs can be a big cause of poor performance due to be run once per row in a query.

Have a read through [this article](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/converting-a-scalar-user-defined-function-to-a-inline-table-valued-function/) which contains an example to demonstrate.

Comment: fair enough.. however there is no point to rewrite the function as it takes 5 sec to run that statement once a day.... It just the execution plan got cocked.

Comment: @Bobb - OK, not going to have a massive impact then. The whole scalar vs inline table UDF topic is worth bearing in mind in general.